# Assigning Variable to Pointer vs Assiging &variable to Pointer

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I am now learning about pointers. This is the sample code from a book:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int i;

        char char_array[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
        int int_array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

        char *char_ptr;
        int *int_ptr;

        char_ptr = char_array;
        int_ptr = int_array;

        for(i=0; i < 5; i++) {
                printf("[integer pointer] points to %p, which contains the integer %d\n", int_ptr, *int_ptr + 1);
                int_ptr = int_ptr + 1;
        }

        for(i=0; i <5; i++) {
                printf("[char pointer] points to %p, which contains the char '%c'\n", char_ptr, *char_ptr);
                char_ptr = char_ptr + 1;
        }
}
```

Q. Would `char *char_ptr = char_array;` change how this code functions in any way or is this the same thing as lines shown above?

Q. Other sample codes from this book also assigns &variable to a pointer, which from I understand means to store the address of a variable to that pointer, (e.g. `char_ptr = &char_array;`). This sample just assigns the variable itself to the pointer, but this program still manages to print the memory addresses that the pointer points to. Why or why not use `char_ptr = &char_array;` in this context? Or does it not make a difference?

```
> kingvon@KingVon:~/Desktop/asm$ gcc pointertypes.c
> kingvon@KingVon:~/Desktop/asm$ ./a.out [integer pointer] points to
> 0x7ffc225227a0, which contains the integer 2 [integer pointer] points
> to 0x7ffc225227a4, which contains the integer 3 [integer pointer]
> points to 0x7ffc225227a8, which contains the integer 4 [integer
> pointer] points to 0x7ffc225227ac, which contains the integer 5
> [integer pointer] points to 0x7ffc225227b0, which contains the integer
> 6 [char pointer] points to 0x7ffc225227c3, which contains the char 'a'
> [char pointer] points to 0x7ffc225227c4, which contains the char 'b'
> [char pointer] points to 0x7ffc225227c5, which contains the char 'c'
> [char pointer] points to 0x7ffc225227c6, which contains the char 'd'
> [char pointer] points to 0x7ffc225227c7, which contains the char 'e'
> kingvon@KingVon:~/Desktop/asm$
```

Edit- typo

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay

Comment: Assuming there is a typo in this statement `int_ptr = int_ptr = 1;` and you mean `int_ptr = int_ptr + 1;`.

Comment: @H.S. yes you are correct -edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Q1:

> Q. Would `char *char_ptr = char_array;` change how this code functions in any way or
> is this the same thing as lines shown above?

```
char char_array[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
char *char_ptr; // declaration
char_ptr = char_array; // assignment
```

**Ans:** Both are same.
In the first one(in question) `char_ptr` declaration and initialization are done in same line and in second one they are done separately.

For Q2:

> Why or why not use char_ptr = &char_array; in this context? Or does it not make a difference?

**Ans:** In the code above shown `char_array` is an array of 5 characters, when you use its name to assign to a pointer
it basically means you are assigning address of its first element, so the expressions

```
char_ptr = char_array; // 1. decl & init done separately
char *char_ptr = char_array; //2. decl & init done same line
char *char_ptr = &char_array[0]; //3. same as 2
char *char_ptr = &char_array; // 4. this is not the correct way will give you warning about this usage, its needs char (*)[5] ptr;
```

all print the address of the starting element of the array.
The expressions

`char *char_ptr = &char_array[0];` and `char *char_ptr = &char_array;` are different but they give the same address

Comment: That makes a lot more sense, so an array essentially works like a pointer that points to specifically assigned elements(addresses).. I now have a much better understanding

Answer (score 3):

A. Yes, this is same things as lines shown above.

A. From C11 Standards#6.3.2.1p3 *[emphasis added]*

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, **an expression that has type ''array of type'' is converted to an expression with type ''pointer to type'' that points to the initial element of the array object** and is not an lvalue. ....

So, in these statements

```
        char_ptr = char_array;
        int_ptr = int_array;
```

`char_array` is converted to pointer of type `char *` that points to the initial element of the `char_array` and `int_array` is converted to pointer of type `int *` that points to the initial element of the `int_array`.

Comment: To make sure I understand: Would `char_ptr[2]` point to  `char_array[2]` in this context?

Comment: After this statement, `char_ptr = char_array;`, the `char_ptr` will point to the first element of `char_array` i.e. element at `[0]` index.

Answer (score 1):

> Q. Would char *char_ptr = char_array; change how this code functions
> in any way or is this the same thing as lines shown above?

`*char_ptr = char_array;` is the same thing as the lines shown above.

---

> Q. Other sample codes from this book also assigns &variable to a pointer, which from I understand means to store the address of a variable to that pointer, (e.g. char_ptr = &char_array;). This sample just assigns the variable itself to the pointer, but this program still manages to print the memory addresses that the pointer points to. Why or why not use char_ptr = &char_array; in this context? Or does it not make a difference?

What you want to do here is **assigning the address** of a variable (an array) **to a pointer**. In order to get the address of an array, you simply use the array name, so you don't need the `&` operator to get the address of an array. Refer to this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/whats-difference-between-array-and-array-for-int-array5/) for more details.

The `&` operator is used in case you want to use a pointer to point to a variable. Refer to this [article](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/d/dereference-operator.htm#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20programming%2C%20a%20dereference,with%20an%20asterisk%20(*).) to understand more about `*` and `&` operators

```c
char *p1;
char *p2;
char var;
char arr[5];

p1 = &var
p2 = arr;
```

**Edit**: Add another way to initialize pointer

```c
char var;
char arr[5];

char *p1 = &var; // char *p1 = var is not correct
char *p2 = arr;
```

Comment: So it would not be appropriate to assign a variable itself `int *p1 = integer1` whereas integer1 is an `int`? What is shown is the sample code from the book is only appropriate when assigning an array to a pointer? Pointers kinda have my brain scrambled up lol